# Assembly argument error

Tags: assembly, arm

I have the following ARM assembly code to diff two images:

```
void diff(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b, unsigned char *c, int length) {
    asm volatile(
        "1:                 \n"
        "vld4.u8 {d0,d1,d2,d3}, [%0]!       \n" // load
        "vld4.u8 {d4,d5,d6,d7}, [%1]!       \n" // load
        "vabd.u8 d0, d0, d4         \n"
        "vabd.u8 d1, d1, d5         \n"
        "vabd.u8 d2, d2, d6         \n"
        "vabd.u8 d3, d3, d7         \n"
        "vst4.u8 {d0,d1,d2,d3}, [%2]!       \n" // store back 0, 1, 2 and 3
        "subs %3, %3, #16           \n" // 16 processed per loop
        "bgt 1b                 \n" // Loop back if not done
        :"+r"(a),                   // %0
        "+r"(b),                    // %1
        "+r"(c),                    // %2
        "+r"(length)                    // %3      // output registers
        :                       // input registers
        : "memory", "cc", "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3"    // Clobber List
    );
}
```

It segfaults. I think that I have a problem in the clobber list. Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: _Can anyone point out the problem?_ A debugger can ;)

Comment: Fire up your debugger and see which line causes the segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was somewhere else in the code and I was obsessed with assembly problem. Sorry...

Comment: You should change vld4/vst4 to vld1/vst1 accordingly in addition. There is no need for interleave / deinterleave in this case. They just consume extra cycles for no purpose at all.